# When GroupBy() is used, navigation property is not loaded, although includes are specified

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I am using Entity Framework Code First to model 2 entities with a 1-1 relationship:

```
public class ElementRevision
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int ElementId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ElementRevisionExtents ElementRevisionExtents { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class ElementRevisionExtents
{
    public virtual ElementRevision ElementRevision { get; set; }
    public virtual double MinX { get; set; }
    public virtual double MinY { get; set; }
    public virtual double MaxX { get; set; }
    public virtual double MaxY { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to search for `ElementRevision`s with IDs 1, 2 or 3 and take only the last revision associated with unique revision id. This is the query that I'm using and ElementRevisions are taken correctly according to my business rules:

```
_context.Set<ElementRevision>()
    .Include(x => x.ElementRevisionExtents)
    .Where(x => new [] { 1, 2, 3 }.Contains(x.Id))
    .GroupBy(x => x.ElementId)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToArray();
```

The problem is that the result doesn't contaion `ElementRevisionExtents` property, it is null. [Here](http://code-ninja.org/blog/2014/07/24/entity-framework-never-call-groupby-todictionary/) is discribed a related problem.

How to rewrite this in order to find navigation property filled in?

Comment: Try moving the `Include` after `Select`.  If it doesn't help, you are out of luck.

Comment: _context is hidden into repository, and Include() and Where() clauses are called exactly in this order and they could not be rearranged. The repository takes include and where expressions and returns IQueryable on which we could call what ever LINQ we want.

Comment: Well, then as I said, you are out of luck :( The drawbacks of the over encapsulation.